# Plausible Liveness on Casper FFG

Tags: casper

[image: Plausible liveness from arxiv]

This is from the Casper FFG document on [Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09437.pdf).

1. Is **a** higher than **b**? If so how is **b** the target checkpoint if it is lower?
2. If **a'** is a descendant of a (which I take means a previous checkpoint) how does **h(a') = h(b) + 1** look like?

Comment: Can you also give me the brief example you showed to Meshugah? I have the same question about Plausible liveness. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rode this a few weeks ago. Let's try to explain it.

**Supermajority links are the way in which the checkpoints are related more efficiently**, as you can see on the photo provided, on figure C, **supermajority links let us verify the blocks/chain so much faster** because let us make **"safe assumptions"**

- A is the highest **justified checkpoint**.
- Target checkpoint B is **the highest on everyone is betting now (more than 2/3 as the protocol requires**.
- Then, if any A'(descendant of the highest justified checkpoint) **which is obviously justified because it's a descendant of a justified checkpoint**, has a greater height than the target checkpoint B, we can assume, we can go directly to look at A checkpoint. And to don't loose this time evaluating the checkpoint B, is why the supermajority links are implemented.

[image: Support to explanation]

**EDIT** Add the graph where Account safety and Plausible Liveness are demonstrated:
[image: Helping graph]

The paper's description of the picture and site where apply the example.

[image: description]

Here you have the definitions as the paper/Article says:
[image: Definitions]

Well, hope it helps!

Comment: Could you give me a very brief example using the diagram. There isn't an 'A' so if you could give me an example with an 'A' and 'B' marked, that would be spectacular.

Comment: Done, hope it helps!

Comment: hahaha thanks, but i posted this question originally because there was only a diagram for Accountable safety and not Plausible liveness. Does the second diagram provide a correct example?

Comment: Yes, the thing is that the Plausible Liveness and Accountable Safety go together. Explained and on the action.